# For loop with pointers and a terminating null

Tags: c++, null

```
char charArray[10];
char* pArray = charArray;
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
*pArray = '\0';
pArray++;
}
```

From this fragment, what does the *pArray = '\0'; mean?
I cannot understand this.

Comment: This is not a range-based for loop.

Comment: This is terrible, terrible, teeeerrible code. Don't even look at it. Unnecessary `char` array instead of a string, unnecessary pointer to array, unnecessary for loop, unnecessary `\0` reset. It's just terrible. Just stay away from who wrote it.

Comment: Is it me or this whole snippet could just be `char charArray[10] = { 0 };` ?

Comment: @Fanael Sometimes a raw array is just fine. But you need to understand its limitations.

Comment: If this is going to be a C-string, only the first character needs to be 0.

Comment: I suggest you pick up a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++, read it, **and** pay attention to it's contents.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: its*

Answer (score 10):

Before the loop pointer `pArray` points to the first character of array `charArray` due to its initialization.

```
char* pArray = charArray;
```

So inside the loop at the first iteration `*pArray` yields reference to the first character of the array. Thus the referenced character is assigned by character literal '\0'.

```
*pArray = '\0';
```

Then the pointer is incermented

```
pArray++;
```

and points to the next character. So at the next iteration the second character of the array will be set to '\0'.
As the loop has 10 iterations then all 10 characters of the array will be initialized by '\0'.

This could be done much simpler in the array definition

```
char charArray[10] = {};
```

In this case also all 10 characters of the array will be initialized by '\0'.

In C the equivalent construction will look as

```
char charArray[10] = { '\0' };
```

Take into account that if the variable pArray is needed only inside the loop to initialize the elements of the array then it is better to write the loop the following way (if you want to use a pointer):

```
const size_t N = 10;
char charArray[N];

for ( char *pArray = charArray; pArray != charArray + N; ++pArray )
{
  *pArray = '\0';
}
```

In fact this loop is equivalent to the internal realization of standard algorithm `std::fill` that you could use.

For example

```
const size_t N = 10;
char charArray[N];

std::fill( charArray, charArray + N, '\0' );
```

Or you could use standard functions `std::begin` and `std::end` to specify the first and the last iterators fot the array.

Comment: This answers the question literally, but answering questions literally makes little to no sense with such horrible questions.

Comment: @Griwes It is not a horrible question. And the answer has a great sense because it ANSWERS THE QUESTION and gives understanding of C++ constructions and definitions. I think that the problem is not with the question but it is with you.

Comment: @Griwes: The code does make sense. To say it doesn't is incorrect. Are you suggesting incorrect answers are better than correct ones?

Comment: @Griwes There is not enough information in the question to determine whether it is a good idea to use `std::string`. And simply suggesting that without explaining the implications wouldn't be too good either.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I am saying "this code makes no sense, don't try to understand it" is better than "this code does this and this" when it comes to code as horrible as this abomination we can see in the question.

Comment: @Griwes  By the way I would like to mention that for example char charArray[10] = {}; is not a C construction:).

Comment: @Griwes  It seems that my answer to the question is also very useful for you. Now you will know that the mentioned above construction is not a valid C construction C does not allow an empty initializer list.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, ok, point taken here; apparently GCC only *warns* about this at -pedantic, which is ultimately retarded.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a better alternative to that terrible code, if you want to use strings:

```
std::string str;
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want an array of 10 characters, you can use:

```
std::array<char, 10> arr;
arr.fill('\0');
```

If you want a resizable array that will initially contain 10 characters, use:

```
std::vector<char> vec(10, '\0');
```

Answer (score 3):

The character literal `'\0'` is a NUL character with the value of 0x00. This loop zeros the array.